# table last row border visible

Tags: html, xhtml, css

even after setting the tr:last-child's border: none, border is still visible. The edit button should be after the last row. But it got position left. http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/mBfk8/ Here is how it should be [image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a floating `<tr>` and a floating `</div>`:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="para">
        <table id="info-table">
            <tr>
                <td>name:</td>
                <td id="name">name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>id:</td>
                <td id="myid">myuid</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>email:</td>
                <td id="email">mysuperemail@email.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr> <!-- WHY? -->
         </table>
    </div>
<div class="edit">
    <button type="submit">edit</button>
</div>
</div> <!-- WHY? -->
```

Get rid of them like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="para">
        <table id="info-table">
            <tr>
                <td>name:</td>
                <td id="name">name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>id:</td>
                <td id="myid">myuid</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>email:</td>
                <td id="email">mysuperemail@email.com</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </div>
<div class="edit">
    <button type="submit">edit</button>
</div>
```

In the future [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) ;)

Comment: thanks. Its a typo. While copying I copied the extra divs. I removed the extra tr and the border isn't visible anymore. But I couldn't get the edit button in its proper place

Comment: @dragonfly - Oh! Sorry, I didn't take note of the edit button problems.

Comment: @dragonfly - Why do you have a `float:right` in the CSS rule `#wrapper .para table#info-table`?